# print not happening in expected order`

Tags: gdb

I have the following gdb script:

```
define test1
printf " Foo "
!date
printf "\n"
end
```

I expected the output to be:
    Foo Tue Oct  1 15:01:58 PDT 2013

However, what I am getting is:
    Tue Oct  1 15:01:58 PDT 2013
     Foo

I feel I need to somehow "flush" the print.  Can someone please help me understand what is going on here.  Why is the output reversed.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a gdb bug to me.  I agree that printf ought to flush its output stream.  Could you please file this in gdb bugzilla?